# How can I apply a pytest mark to a whole subtree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

`pytestmark = pytest.mark.foo` applies this mark to all functions+classes in a module.

My problem is that I have a lot of test modules in a directory and want to apply the testmark to all of them.

How? I don't want to change every module's file.

Answer (score 3):

You can attach the common marker programmatically, e.g. in the [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hookimpl:

```python
import pytest


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        item.add_marker(pytest.mark.foo)
```

If only tests from selected subtrees should be marked, extend the above impl with a test module file check, e.g.

```python
import pathlib
import pytest


# assuming all tests are stored in a `tests` directory
dirs = (pathlib.Path("tests/foo"), pathlib.Path("tests/bar/baz"))

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    for item in items:
        testmod = pathlib.Path(item.fspath)
        if any(config.rootdir / dir in testmod.parents for dir in dirs):
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.foo)
```